# Перебор массива и изменение четных значений

Tags: javascript

Дан массив:

```
var fruits = ["banana", "cherry", "melon", "strawberry"];
```

Необходимо перебрать его с помощью цикла while и у всех значений с четным индексом изменить регистр на верхний.

Написала следующий код:

```
var i;
while (i < fruits.length - 1) {
    if (fruits[i] % 2 === 0) {
        fruits[i].toUpperCase('');
    } else {
        continue;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: У вас результат `fruits[i].toUpperCase('');` никуда не присваивается. Надо так `fruits[i]=fruits[i].toUpperCase('');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Считать остаток от деления нужно от индекса `i`, а не от элемента массива. А ещё лучше сделать так, чтобы `i` принимало только четные значения. Например, увеличивая значение `i` сразу на 2
2. Хоть это и не совсем ошибка, но всё же метод `toUpperCase` не принимает никаких параметров
3. Метод `toUpperCase` не меняет строку, а возвращает новую, поэтому результат выполнения нужно присваивать обратно в `fruits[i]`
4. `else { continue; }` без увеличения `i` может запросто привести к зацикливанию, да и зачем он тут?
5. Идти нужно до `i < fruits.length`, чтобы не потерять последний четный элемент в массиве нечетной длины

В итоге получается так:

```js
var fruits = ["banana", "cherry", "melon", "strawberry"];
var i = 0;
while (i < fruits.length) {
  fruits[i] = fruits[i].toUpperCase();
  i += 2;
}
console.log(fruits);
```

---

Если по заданию требуется использовать `while`, то код таков, но вообще `for` выглядит здесь более уместно:

```js
var fruits = ["banana", "cherry", "melon", "strawberry"];
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i += 2)
  fruits[i] = fruits[i].toUpperCase();

console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: Да, for и понятнее как-то, но задание действительно было на закрепление while. Хоть разобралась, как его правильно применить. Спасибо!

Comment: @АлисаГулий не используйте while, это допотопный метод.

Comment: @EVG откуда такая категоричность? Если, например, нужно выполнять итерации пока выполняется какое-то условие, то чем вы воспользуетесь вместо `while (condition)`?

Comment: @EVG у меня начальный уровень, я просто пытаюсь осилить домашние задания. Что задали, в том и разбираюсь:)

Comment: @Regent ну разве что для этого, но если извращнуться можно и через setInterval запилить бесконечный цикл пока условие не выполнится и потом убить функцию)). Хотя setInterval в 2 раза медленей, там кажись 4 мс против 2мс в while ))). В любом случае редко на практик while встречаю)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var fruits = ["banana ", "cherry ", "melon ", "strawberry "];
var i = -1;
while (++i < fruits.length) {
  if (!(i % 2)) {
    fruits[i] = fruits[i].toUpperCase();
  }
}
console.log(fruits);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let fruits = ["banana", "cherry", "melon", "strawberry"];

console.info(fruits.map((el, i) => !(i % 2) ? el.toUpperCase() : el));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fruits = ["banana", "cherry", "melon", "strawberry"];
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
i%2 != 0 ? fruits[i] = fruits[i].toUpperCase() : ''
}
console.log(fruits)
```